# Why not keep this kind of question open?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

The question of mine **was** [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72641/training-conversation).

I know question without answers isn't prefereable. But this type of questions still relevant.

The strange thing is we can find a final answer to question (as I said, the better 5 links).

If the problem is with the reputation this wouldnt be the problem, the only thing should change is the admnistrator **protect** the question.

Another argument is if someone come here and ask for a translation, this question will be answered (because it has a goal). But, if another user suggest another translation, maybe, the answer (by the owner of the question) will change to this new one.

So, Why not keep this kind of question open (even if protected)? This kind of question is unhelpful?

Comment: "Better five" is still subjective.

Comment: [ELU is not ESL](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/703/is-elu-becoming-esl) - get used to it.

Comment: The question (and possible answers) may be "helpful" to some people, but so would lots of other things ELU doesn't cater for. We're mainly here to analyse and better understand our language (sometimes, second or "would-be" language), not organise lesson plans and recommend study aids for students.

Comment: "I would like a good site (free and paid ones) to improve my conversation" is a so-called shopping recommendation question. This kind of question is indeed unhelpful *the way you ask it*. I recommend reading the SE blog entry ["Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) which not only explains *why* it is unhelpful but also points out *how* it could easily be turned into something way more helpful. For the impatient, the gist of it is "don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us *what you need to learn* to tell what you should buy."

Answer (score 4):

The reason your question has been closed is already given underneath it. As you should be aware, EL&U is a Q&A site. Questions asked here are expected to lead to a *specific answer*, not cause an *extended debate*. Your question is too broad and certainly doesn't have a *specific answer*. Also, it is [out of scope for this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

A snapshot of the link:

[image]

If you go through the above mentioned link, you will seee which questions you *can/should not* ask on this site.

As for the **translation** related questions, you are mistaken. The page (link above), explicitly mentions *"translation and non-English languages"* under the category of questions which are **not** to be asked here. Such questions are either *closed* or *migrated* to a sister site.

And for **protecting your question**, let me quote why a question is *protected*:

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site.

Comment: Well, the truth is. I have no interest to fight a little much for this. I really think change the faq and the site policy will became it better (and create a new method, with another name, like protected to this kind of question). But, if we have a answer with 6 votes up and my question as 3 down. I'm ok. I will return if I just have specific question. Cya.

Comment: @GarouDan There *used* to be a format for this, but sitewide (SO included) this was changed. I don't think people will be willing to change it back.

Answer (score 2):

The question has been closed as not constructive, which means that:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

A request for a list of web sites you could use to learn English is a request for a list, which is not a kind of question that is welcome on Stack Exchange sites.
First off, that type of list would be rather subjective, as it depends from your knowledge of English; it is also subjective because you would get different answers, if you ask the question to different people. The answers would not be supported by facts, and they would not require a specific expertise. Are there experts in choosing the web site that better helps you in improving your skills in English?

The [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) then says:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.